# How do I avoid invaliding the iterator using `ReplaceInstWithValue()`?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm, clang++

In the program below, when I use the `ReplaceInstWithValue()`, it go into an infinite loop, since I replace the `add` instruction with a sequence of instructions containing an `add` instruction. Thus, the program prints something along the lines of `xor`, `add`, `mul`, ...

I guess the problem has to do with instructions inserted into the list of `BasicBlock` instructions, i.e., the list for which iteration is performed.

How do I fix the problem, so that I proceed with the next element in the list, ignoring the inserted instructions?

Is the only way to put all points of insertion into a data structure and perform the substitution after iteration has finished?

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/Utils/BasicBlockUtils.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace llvm;

namespace {
struct CountOp : public FunctionPass {    
    static char ID;

    CountOp() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {

        for (Function::iterator bs = F.begin(), be = F.end(); bs != be; ++be) {
            for (BasicBlock::iterator is = bs->begin(), ie = be->end(); is != ie; ++is) {
                Instruction& inst  = *is;
                BinaryOperator* binop = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&inst);
                if (!binop) {
                    continue;
                }
                unsigned opcode = binop->getOpcode();
                errs() << binop->getOpcodeName() << "\n";

                if (opcode != Instruction::Add) {

                    continue;
                }

                IRBuilder<> builder(binop);
                Value* v = builder.CreateAdd(builder.CreateXor(binop->getOperand(0), binop->getOperand(1)), 
                                             builder.CreateMul(ConstantInt::get(binop->getType(), 2), 
                                                               builder.CreateAnd(binop->getOperand(0), binop->getOperand(1))));

                ReplaceInstWithValue(bs->getInstList(), is, v);
            } 
        }

        errs() << "\n";
        return true;
    }
};
}

char CountOp::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<CountOp> X("opCounter", "Counts opcodes per functions", false, false);
```

Comment: Why do you increment be in the outer loop?

Comment: That's basic blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As w1ck3dg0ph3r points out, you are incrementing `be` in the outer loop when you should be incrementing `bs`. This should fix your infinite loop issue. The `llvm::IRBuilder` inserts the instructions before the instruction pointed by the iterator passed to the constructor, so you do not need to make any other changes.

Comment: Actually, changing to `++bs` doesn't fix the issue. I still go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Do you suggests that I should replace `ReplaceInstWithValue` by something else?

Comment: That's strange. Have you remembered to recompile your pass? Could you provide an example LLVM IR input? I tested it myself and it works fine: http://pastebin.com/dR8dbhCu

Comment: I will upload it later, but it is basically just a simple .ll file containing a main function, two variables, addition of the variables, and return of the result.

Comment: Yes, I have recompile :)